# Only change inactive color of one radio in Framework7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-framework-7

I am trying to change the so called inactive color of **only one** radio button in Framework7. I know that with this css variable `--f7-radio-inactive-color: <yourcolor>;` I can set the inactive color for all my radio buttons.

But I would like to change the inactive color for one (the currently selected) radio button only. I do not know a lot about css variables, so I tried this

```
input:checked[name=color-radio]{
       --f7-radio-inactive-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

but it did not work.

If you like to play around with my minimal example, it can be found [here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/puz96k3a/2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe css variables are scope aware so the setting it not on `:root` won't have an affect.

But you can manually set the `<i>` to a colour and it displays correctly. Just you need to reset all of the `<i>` before setting them all again.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/r0jkq2o7/2/

Comment: Thanks, this is a good enough workaround for me. However the behaviour is not exactly the same, because the color is changed while the radio is active, while normally the radio would stay in it's active color style, until another radio is selected. So basically the effect can only be observed then, while now it is visible 
immediately. But I should be able, to improve this to the point where the behaviour is the same.